# Check if macro argument is a tikz pattern

Tags: tikz-pgf, pattern

Is it possible to check if a given argument is a defined tikz pattern (using the pattern library)?  I'd like to have a macro

```
\IfPatternTF{#1}{executed if #1 is a pattern}{executed if #1 isn't a pattern}
```

Ideally,  \IfPatternTF would fully expand #1 before checking but I can probably manage that myself once I know how to check if it's a pattern.

Note that I'd be equally happy being able to test if something is a color since I want this for the purpose of deciding to either do a fill= or a pattern= in the command.  However, the answers for checking if xcolor colors are defined doesn't help since that doesn't tell me if it's an acceptable argument for fill= in tikz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a pattern `foo` is declared in the standard `pattern` library, the control sequence `\pgf@pattern@name@foo` is defined; similarly, `\pgf@pattern@name@meta@foo` if the pattern is declared with `\pgfdeclarepattern` from the `patterns.meta` library.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,patterns.meta}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\IfPatternTF}[1]{%
  \ifcsname pgf@pattern@name@#1\endcsname
    % defined pattern
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo
  \else
    \ifcsname pgf@pattern@name@meta@#1\endcsname
      % defined meta pattern
      \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo
    \else
    % undefined pattern
    \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

% declare a pattern for testing; this is from the PGF/TikZ manual
\pgfdeclarepattern{
  name=hatch,
  parameters={\hatchsize,\hatchangle,\hatchlinewidth},
  bottom left={\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{-.1pt}},
  top right={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}},
  tile size={\pgfpoint{\hatchsize}{\hatchsize}},
  tile transformation={\pgftransformrotate{\hatchangle}},
  code={
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\hatchlinewidth}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{-.1pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}}
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{-.1pt}{\hatchsize+.1pt}}
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{\hatchsize+.1pt}{-.1pt}}
    \pgfusepath{stroke}
  }
}

\begin{document}

\IfPatternTF{horizontal lines}{existing pattern}{non existing pattern}

\IfPatternTF{hatch}{existing pattern}{non existing pattern}

\IfPatternTF{foo}{existing pattern}{non existing pattern}

\end{document}
```

Beware that delving with internals is not guaranteed to work forever. You might make a feature request to the PGF/Ti*k*Z maintainers.

[image]

There's nothing to worry in case the name is stored in a macro, provided it is fully expandable. So `\newcommand\foo{horizontal lines}` will make `\IfPatternTF{\foo}{true}{false}` do the right thing.